# Computing new transform after changing center of rotation

Tags: wpf, vb.net, matrix, rotation, transformation

### Short version

Given a transform matrix M1, original center of rotation P1 and new center of rotation P2, what is the correct way to compute the new transform matrix M2 so as to keep object's current **position** and **rotation** intact?

### Long version

I'm working on a vector drawing application that allows user to rotate objects using `Thumb` controls. Rotation works fine around the center of the object. I have set `RenderTransformOrigin` to `0.5,0.5`, so simply setting `RenderTransform` to `<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Rotation}" />` does the job for me.

Now I need to allow user to change the pivot point, or center of rotation. I added another `Thumb` that allows users to place the pivot point anywhere they like. My idea was to simply bind this thumb's location to `RenderTransformOrigin` or `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties of my `RotateTransform` to start rotating around the new center.

The problem however is that as soon as user moves the pivot thumb to a new location, `RotateTransform` computes the new transform matrix and moves the object accordingly, which is counter-productive, since the pivot thumb should only act as the center of rotation *during* the rotate operation.

After having spent the better part of the past 2 weeks with this, I have realized that I need to compute the new transform matrix for my object the keeps the current position and rotation intact while moving the center of rotation. Is there a built-in or custom way to do that?

### Edit

Just to clarify it further, here is how it should go:

1. User drops a new object, say a rectangle.
2. Pivot point by default is at 0.5, 0.5, i.e. center of the object.
3. User rotates the object using **Rotation thumb**. Object rotates around its center since pivot point is at the center. User sets rotation to 45 degrees and leaves the rotation thumb.
4. User now grabs the **Pivot thumb** and drags it around. Ideally this should only move the pivot thumb and must not affect the object's current position or rotation in any way, but currently it does because my `RotateTransform`'s CenterX and CenterY are bound to pivot's position.
5. I can avoid direct binding of `RotateTransform` to Pivot's position, but at whatever point I assign the new center to it, the RotateTransform will compute the new position and move object accordingly.
6. My idea is that at the point of assignment, we must compute the new transformation matrix using the new pivot and assign it to the object before assigning the center of rotation.

Comment: I hope I understand your intent correctly. To me what you need is 1) Compute the new matrix, 2) ask user of they would like new transformation matrix to be applied. When they do, then 3) use new matrix.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara: No. 1 is correct. The rest are implied. As user moves the pivot point to a new location, we must compute and apply the new matrix because any subsequent rotations will be centered around the new pivot.

Comment: I thought you said, you want to avoid object to move when pivot thumb is moved?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara: Yes, that's correct too. The new transform matrix would be such that applying it would not affect the *current* position and rotation of the object, so that user doesn't get the impression that the pivot point has anything to do with the current state of the object. Only future rotations are affected.

Comment: You compute new new rotation matrix and store it somewhere. You need to multiply new rotation matrix to transformation matrix only when new rotation is re-run, otherwise you just use the old rotation matrix.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara: I added more details. See if those help you get the picture.

Comment: A transform matrix does not have an inherit pivot point. A rotation around one point is identical to a rotation around another point plus a translation. The resulting matrixes are identical in both cases. You have to follow what Zamrony has said, "multiply rotation matrixes". If you have rotatated an object around a certain pivot, keep that transform matrix. Then rotate around another pivot, and multiply that transform matrix by the previous one.

Comment: As a note, for what you are trying to achieve, setting RenderTransformOrigin makes things complicated, because you may have to convert its relative units to absolute units of your thumb position. Better only operate with absolute units.

Comment: @Clemens: I'm controlling translation through `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, and rotation through `RenderTransform`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to do that. Better translate, scale and rotate the shapes by a single transform, either a TransformGroup with appropriate child elements, or a MatrixTransform with an appropriately calculated Matrix.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara: Do I need to compute the new rotation matrix upon pivot thumb's movement, or upon rotation thumb's movement?

Comment: @dotNET because you want pivot movement does not affect object immediately, I compute new rotation matrix upon rotation thumb's movement.

Comment: @dotNET I'm wondering if you solved that problem. Currently I'm facing the very same issue. Following that solutions I can't solve it anyway. Would you be so kind to present pseudocode or at least operations sequence?

Comment: @KamilNowak: See my answer.

Comment: @dotNET Thank you very much! I'm using your code but only to clarify I have some questions :) 1. How exactly do you calculate RotationThumbOffsetFromPivot? 2. Is RotateCenterPos just the pivot coordinates? 3. I can't figure RotateHandlePos meaning. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KamilNowak: My rotation thumb is placed slight above the object (just like Word/Excel shapes). RotationThumbOffsetFromPivot denotes the vertical offset of the thumb from the object.Sorry I did it years ago; can't recall it in full detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering @KamilNowak's request in the comments above, a long time has passed since then, but I just managed to dig this out from my code repository. Hope this helps you find your way forward. You basically need to call this function AFTER you change the location of your pivot point (is in vb.net but u should be able translate):

```
'_Designer is the main Canvas control on which all drawing objects are placed
Friend Sub AdjustLocationAfterPivotShift(_Designer As Canvas)
  'RectangularObject is the underlying VM object that represents my shape
  Dim RO = DirectCast(Me.DataContext, RectangularObject)

  'My control template has Thumb elements for translation, rotation, scaling and pivot. Here I'm using rotate and pivot thumbs. Use your controls instead.
  Dim DIRotateThumb As RotateThumb = VisualTreeExtensions.GetVisualDescendent(Of RotateThumb)(Me)
  Dim _RotateHandle = DirectCast(DIRotateThumb.Template.FindName("PART_RotateEllipse", DIRotateThumb), Shapes.Ellipse)

  Dim RotateHandlePos As Point = _RotateHandle.TranslatePoint(New Point(5, 5), _Designer)
  Dim RotateCenterPos As Point = Me.TranslatePoint(New Point(RO.PivotX + RO.Size.Width / 2, RO.PivotY + RO.Size.Height / 2), _Designer)
  'ROTATION_HANDLE_OFFSET is vertical distance between control and rotation thumb
  Dim RotationThumbOffsetFromPivot As New Point(-RO.PivotX, -RO.PivotY - Me.ActualHeight / 2 - ROTATION_HANDLE_OFFSET)

  RO.Rotation = Me.ComputeAngle(RotateCenterPos, RotateHandlePos, RotationThumbOffsetFromPivot)
  Dim NewLocation As Point = ComputeLocationDelta(New Point(RO.PivotX, RO.PivotY), RO.LastPivot.ToPoint(), RO.Rotation)

  RO.Location.X += NewLocation.X
  RO.Location.Y += NewLocation.Y

  'Set LastPivot to current pivot location after adjusting location
  RO.LastPivot.X = RO.PivotX
  RO.LastPivot.Y = RO.PivotY
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Computes X and Y delta that must be added to object's current location to 
    account for pivot's changed location.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="currentPivot"></param>
''' <param name="originalPivot"></param>
''' <param name="angle"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Private Function ComputeLocationDelta(currentPivot As Point, originalPivot As 
  Point, angle As Double) As Point
  Dim h = currentPivot.X - originalPivot.X
  Dim v = currentPivot.Y - originalPivot.Y
  Dim trans As System.Windows.Vector = RotateVector2d(h, v, D2R(angle))

  Return New Point(trans.X - h, trans.Y - v)
End Function

Friend Function ComputeAngle(center As Point, pos As Point, offset As Point) As Double
  Dim xDiff = pos.X - center.X
  Dim yDiff = pos.Y - center.Y

  Dim offsetAngle = Math.Atan2(offset.Y, offset.X) * 180 / Math.PI
  Return Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI - offsetAngle
End Function

Friend Shared Function RotateVector2d(x0 As Double, y0 As Double, rad As Double) As Vector
  Dim result As New Vector With {
    .X = x0 * Math.Cos(rad) - y0 * Math.Sin(rad),
    .Y = x0 * Math.Sin(rad) + y0 * Math.Cos(rad)
  }
  Return result
End Function

Friend Shared Function D2R(degree As Double) As Double
  Return (degree Mod 360) * Math.PI / 180
End Function
```

Hope this is not as clear as mud and you can use it to your benefit.

Comment: thank you very much for that code I'm sure it will help a lot!